# Error 'shell:::{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}, this file has no program associated...'

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-8.1, windows-registry, guid

In a unattended installation of `Windows 8.1` x64 (where I've removed some components) the next error will occurs when I try to start the Explorer process from commandline, or doing a double-click on the explorer.exe file, or using the pinned icon on the Taskbar.

I would like to find the missing component (or something else) that is causing this error, but really I didn't removed anything related to explorer.

A messagebox with this caption appears:

> shell:::{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}

And with a message like this (sorry for the bad translation I get the error in Spanish):

> This file has no program associated to realize this action'

That GUID or CLSID `52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1` does not exists on the registry of my host OS (Windows 8), seems that is only for Windows 8.1, and I did not find any info about that GUID 'cause Google just finds two matches from Technet in an unknown language for me:

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1

These are the unique keys that exists on my registry referencing that CLSID:

( Maybe you could notice and advise me of important differences from an original Windows 8.1 fresh installation)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00



; HKCR\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}]
@=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,32,\
  00,32,00,30,00,36,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\open\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\OpenNewWindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"



; HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}]
@=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,32,\
  00,32,00,30,00,36,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\open\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\OpenNewWindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"



; HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}]
@=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,32,\
  00,32,00,30,00,36,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\open\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\OpenNewWindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"



; HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}]
@=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,32,\
  00,32,00,30,00,36,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\open\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\OpenNewWindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"



; HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}]
@=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,32,\
  00,32,00,30,00,36,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\open\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\OpenNewWindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}"
```

Comment: Which components did you remove? Checking the registry key, the `(Default)` value is set to `@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-22067`. By digging inside `shell32.dll.mui` file, you can see string `22067` is "File Explorer".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this in my case by editing this entry after half day of research.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command]
@="%SystemRoot%\\Explorer.exe"
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
```

Comment: what a saviour!

Comment: Any advice for restoring the Win Key + E keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Keyslinger it wasn't restored for you?

Answer (score 18):

I came across this exception on Windows 10.  After customizing my primary account's File Explorer look and layout including removing the Quick Access folder from the navigation panel.

Then when logging in from a different account and trying to open File Explorer, this error popped up.

The quick solution was to change the default view of File Explorer from Quick Access to This PC.  Go to Control Panel, File Explorer Options and change the "Open File Explorer to" option to "This PC".  Then you'll be able to open File Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem is if the HKCR\Folder\shell\opennewwindow key is deleted. Set it to be in the extended menu if you want it File Explorer to work and not see the Open In New Window Menu...

Comment: Thanks! I forgot I removed this an hour ago, looking to fix it took 45 minutes.. Had to check another Win 10 computer to get the original contents, and added it to your solution. I didn't understand the "extended menu" thing, but found another solution, also added.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after changing a setting in the 'File Explorer Options' the day before. Problem solved after setting all these options back to default.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and after a good research I found that in windows one of the reason this errors occurs is when file explorer invokes a particular verb to be executed when it is clicked but does not find it or some of its parts in the registry editor. In my case I had moved the

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow

to a submenu

> Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explorer

and renamed the key to "00opennewwindow" so that it stayed at the top in the sub menu. Since renaming the key was not an option for me what I did was change the "verbed to be invoked" string value in

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Launcher.AllAppsDesktopApplication\Shell\OpenNewWindow

from "opennewwindow" to "00opennewwindow" (try only if you are an advanced user) and it solved the problem or else you can copy the following code in text pad and save as .reg and execute to solve the issue if your key is in the default place.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow]
"LaunchExplorerFlags"=dword:00000001
"MUIVerb"="@windows.storage.dll,-8517"
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"OnlyInBrowserWindow"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
```